# Change and display[remove/add] the available option based on input textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
 <input id="studentnoofinst" type="text" size="20" value=""/>
<select id="studentinst" size="6">
<option value="1">First Installment</option>
<option value="2">Second Installment</option>
<option value="3">Third Installment</option>
<option value="4">Fourth Installment</option>
<option value="5">Fifth Installment</option>
<option value="6">Sixth Installment</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
 $("#studentnoofinst").keyup(function() { 

    //$("select option[value='fb']").prop("selected",true);
    alert("going to change");
    $leap=0;
    $leap=($('#studentnoofinst').val());
    if($leap!=''){
    for(i=$leap;i<=6;i++) {// displaying the no of installments 
        if(i!=$leap){
            $('#studentinst option[value='+i+']').remove();

 }
     }    
    }

});
```

Hi, as shown in the code above i am able to remove the selected row, My question is that i am not able to add the selected option back,How to add the selected row back
P.S:once if enter 4 the last 2 rows are deleted and later if enter 5 only the first 4 rows are display and the 5 row is vomitted.. but it need it

if first time the input =4

ouptut:

```
  <option value="1">First Installment</option>
  <option value="2">Second Installment</option>
  <option value="3">Third Installment</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth Installment</option>
```

if second time the input =5

ouptut:

```
  <option value="1">First Installment</option>
  <option value="2">Second Installment</option>
  <option value="3">Third Installment</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth Installment</option>
  <option value="5">Fifth Installment</option>//vomitted but i need this? add
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ7GF/30/

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve - do you only want the options shown when they match the text in the input field ?

Comment: yup once if enter 4 the rest 2 are deleted and later if enter 5 only the first 4 rows are display and the 5 row is vomitted.. but it need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - merged the changes made by soul:

you could save the options in a variable and add them back:

```
var list = $('#studentinst').html();
$("#studentnoofinst").keyup(function() {
    $('#studentinst').empty().append(list);
    alert("going to change");
    $leap = 0;
    $leap = ($('#studentnoofinst').val());
    if ($leap != '') {
        for (i = $leap; i <= 6; i++) { // displaying the no of installments 
            if (i != $leap) {
                $('#studentinst option[value=' + i + ']').remove();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ7GF/49/

Comment: kewl this is what i needed... but cant we have the same options to be stored as a variable which is in the view page that is <select id="studentinst" size="6">

Comment: @soul i don't really get what you are asking! :)

Comment: bro the variable u have declared var options . Cant we fetch the values from the  id="studentinst"

Comment: Answer or the solution is correct will approve it and accept the answer, but do we need to add the var options is my other question

Answer (score 1):

Once it's removed, it's removed!

If your just going to move a row you can look at jQuery's before, after and append functions.

If you would like to temporary remove a row, and insert it later you should use detach.

If you would like to hide it and show it again later you should use hide and show functions.

Head over to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and look up those functions to see what fits.

Here's a Fiddle with detach(), this keeps all other data intact when the same element is reinserted : http://jsfiddle.net/PQ7GF/50/